# sudo service apache2 restart giving apache2: unrecognized service

Tags: apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04

I removed apache2 before and I reinstalled it on ubuntu 14.04. 
Now I want to restart apache.

Here is how apache was uninstalled:

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2 apache2-utils apache2.2-bin apache2-common
```

and

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

---

After re-installing I tried below

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

but it gives

> $ apache2: unrecognized service

When I check apache version

```
$ apache2 -v
```

> Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server built:   Mar 10 2015
>   13:05:59

What am I missing?

I rebooted my vps but still it's giving the same error.

Answer (score 3):

You might need to reinstall the common package.  Seems like you are missing the init script.  You can check to see if apache2 is in the /etc/init.d/ directory..

```
ls /etc/init.d/
```

If it is missing you can try and reinstall common.  Also you can run reinstall on apache2 as well to see if it replaces files that are missing.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall apache2.2-common
```

Comment: and also double check you still got "apache2-utils" installed (I'm not an Ubuntu package database expert, I just check these things).

Answer (score 0):

I am using `Ubuntu 18.04 Subsystem for Windows 10` and I had that problem when starting my apache2 service for the first time,to fix that you have to recover your `apache2-utils` by typing these commands in your terminal :

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge apache2 apache2-utils
sudo apt-get install --reinstall apache2 apache2-utils
sudo service apache2 start
```

and then check by:

```
sudo service apache2 status
```